# Prove preimage resistance property

Tags: hash, preimage-resistance

Let $ f : \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ and $ g : \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^m$. $h$ is created by concatenate f and g: $ h : \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{n+m}$ with $h(x) = f(x) || g(x)$. How do I prove that both $f$ and $g$ must be preimage resistant if $h$ is to be preimage resistant? Is the same true for 2nd-preimage resistance?

Comment: Is this homework? Either way, what have you tried? Where do you have troubles proving it?

Comment: Yes, it is homework. I know that if h is preimage resistant it must be hard to find x such that h(x)=y with y belongs to Im(h), that means it is hard to find x such that f(x)=p and g(x)=q with y=p||q. I don't know how to proceed from this.

Comment: Are you sure both have to be preimage resistant for $h$ to be? Say $g$ is not. That means given a digest $y=y_1||y_2$ from $h$ where $y_2$ is the output of $g$, we can find a value $x'$ (which may or may not be $x$) such that $g(x')=y_2$. What we don't know is if $f(x')=y_1$. Likely it isn't if $f$ is preimage resistant. Then $h(x')=f(x')||g(x')=f(x')||y_2$ which is likely not $y$.

Comment: Does your definition of preimage resistance for $f:\{0,1\}^*\mapsto\{0,1\}^n$ require the hardness of finding a preimage to be some function of $n$? I can't think of a proof of what you ask without that (much to the contrary if the required difficulty was independent of $n$ it seems possible to exhibit a counterexample).

Comment: What is $m$? $\:$ (in the opening post) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @mikeazo: I'm sure that both $f$ and $g$ have to be preimage resistant.

Comment: @fgrieu : My definition of preimage resistant: For almost all $y \in Im(h)$ it is hard to find $x$ such that $h(x)=y$

Comment: @RickyDemer : I have edited the post g: $\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^m$

Comment: @user3283751: With that definition of _preimage resistant_ where _hard_ is absolute rather than determined by the width of the result, I doubt that "_both f and g must be preimage resistant if h is to be preimage resistant_". Hint: what would a counterexample look like? What properties must it have? Find one, that's easy unless I err deeply!

Comment: @fgrieu : $f(x) =0^n$ is not preimage resistant ,suppose $g(x)$ is a preimage resistant function. $h(x) = 0^n \| g(x)$.So $h(x)$ must be preimage resistant because otherwise $g(x)$ will not be preimage resistant. Is that a right counterexample?

Comment: Yes, I thought the same. You'd have to measure preimage resistance as average complexity to find the preimage. If it is exponential in $n$, it would be easy to prove your statement.

Comment: @fgrieu : where is it lacking ?

Comment: @user3283751: The counterexample itself is fine (though I would also decide a value of $n$), but the proof is lacking (in detail), that is: is not detailed enough to be acceptable. You need to prove that finding a premimage by $h$ for almost every element of $Im(h)$ is easy, by explaining how that can be done assuming what you hypothesized. Also, be sure you understand/justify on what grounds you can "_suppose $x\mapsto g(x)$ is a preimage resistant function_"; it is not immediately evident that because you have homework about preimage resistant functions, such things must exist.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a hash function $H : \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{k}$ is preimage resistant if

Given any hash $y$ it is infeasible to find any message $x$ such that $H(x)=y$ .

Now for your case lets assume that one of the functions, say $g$, is not preimage resistance.
Now suppose we have a $h-$hash of unknown message $x$, we know, from the construction of $h$ , that the last m bits of our hash are equal to $g(x)$.

Since $g$ is not preimage resistant we somehow are able to find the value of $x$, which obviously means that we have found the message $x$ that results in a certain $h$-hash

Comment: Nope. You have found $x$ such that $g(x)=$ the last $m$ bits of $h(x)$. But there is no guarantee that the first $n$ bits of $h(x)$ are equal to $f(x)$.

Comment: Ok, I see. But I think by not-preimage-resistant he meant possible to find the exact(assumed) preimage when given the hash.

Comment: @mikeazo thanks now I see where my logic goes wrong. I assumed there is one to one correspondence between the hash and the preimage.

Comment: "Given any hash $y$ it is infeasible to find any message $x$ such that $H(x)=y$" That statement is not a valid characterization of preimage resistance. In fact it trivially does not hold for any function. For any $y=H(x)$ there exists an attacker that just outputs $x$. What you are trying to say is probably that "For a uniformly chosen $x$ the probability that an efficient adversary, given $y=H(x)$, outputs $x'$ such that $H(x')=y$ is negligible."